# How to load `task_kwargs` from `TaskResult` model in `django_celery_results`?

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

I'm using `django_celery_results` to save results of some celery tasks. Each task gets `kwargs` as input which at the end gets saved in `task_kwargs` field of `TaskResult`.

Im having trouble loading those `kwargs` later from the way they get saved in DB. For example this is one entry:

```
"{'config_file_path': '/path/to/configs/some_config.json'}"
```

Simple example of accessing the field value:

```
tkwargs = TaskResult.objects.get(id=1).task_kwargs
```

for which i get the above string.

What is a straightforward way to get `task_kwargs` as a python dictionary instead of that string?

Comment: json.load() it?

Comment: `json.load(tkwargs)` doesnt throw an error, but it returns the same string. For example:
`json.loads(tkwargs)['config_file_path']` returns `TypeError: string indices must be integers` instead of the desired `config_file_path` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have:

```py
args = json.loads(task.task_kwargs)
if isinstance(args, str):
    args = args.replace("'", '"')
    args = json.loads(args)
```

Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: See also https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/issues/113

Comment: Thanks man, will test it out on monday and accept if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Wish this were easier with this package (why aren't they deserialized out of the model?):

```py
recent_tasks = TaskResult.objects.order_by('-date_done')[:10]
tasks_list = [
    {
        'task_id': task.task_id,
        'task_name': task.task_name,
        'task_args': json.loads((task.task_args or "null").replace("()", "null").replace('"null"', 'null')),
        'task_kwargs': json.loads((json.loads(task.task_kwargs or 'null') or "null").replace("'", '"')),
        'status': task.status,
        'result': json.loads(task.result),
        'date_created': task.date_created,
        'date_done': task.date_done,
        'meta': json.loads(task.meta),
        'worker': task.worker,
        'traceback': task.traceback,
    }
    for task in recent_tasks
]
```